# How to upload a large file with multipart using the TemporaryFile from 1.3.0

Tags: c++, oat++

I'm trying to create an `endpoint` and corresponding swagger `endpoint_info` which uploads a file via multipart. I was hoping to use the `TemporaryFile` to write the parts then iterate the parts from `getAllParts()` to dump them to my final file. I can't seem to get the `endpoint_info` to create the right boundary in my request. I'm getting an exception when I try to create the `PartList`: `Error. No 'boundary' value found in headers`.

```
ENDPOINT_INFO(upload) {
        info->summary =
            "Upload"
        info->addResponse<Object<CommandResponseDto>>(Status::CODE_200,
                                                      "application/json");
        info->addConsumes<oatpp::String>("multipart/form-data");
    }

    ENDPOINT("POST", "upload",
             upload,
             REQUEST(std::shared_ptr<IncomingRequest>, request)) {
        namespace mp = oatpp::web::mime::multipart;
        try {
            mp::PartList multipart(request->getHeaders());
        } catch (const std::exception& e) {
            logger_->error("Error creating multipart object: {}", e.what());
            return create_error_response(e.what());
        }
        mp::PartList multipart(request->getHeaders());

        mp::Reader multipartReader(&multipart);

        multipartReader.setDefaultPartReader(
            mp::createTemporaryFilePartReader("/tmp" /* /tmp directory */));

        request->transferBody(&multipartReader);

        auto parts = multipart.getAllParts();
        for (auto& p : parts) {
            /* print part name and filename */
            logger_->error("Multipart", "Part name={}, filename={}",
                           p->getName()->c_str(), p->getFilename()->c_str());
            
            /* some append all files into one large file */
        }

        return createResponse("OK");
    }
```

I've tried searching around the docs and using both synchronous and asynchronous endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you have a mistake.
When I create my request by Postman, using multipart to send files, it automatically calculated the boundary (I think this's related to the sizes of files when sending the request NOT the endpoint). It's in Content-Type header. Something like this:

> Content-Type: "multipart/form-data; boundary=156466241443238208096850"

About the endpoint, I do the same as you. But I realize in my Windows, my code works with the path "tmp\\" instead of "/tmp".

Hope this helps.
Sorry if my answer is so confusing. Because this's the first time I post.